# PHP Notice Undefined Index for HTML Select Option Tag

Tags: php, html

```
Notice: Undefined index: ArLebel in E:\xampp\htdocs\proj\example\insert.php on line 15.
```

Here is my html code for Dropdown.

```
<tr>
            <td>Level</td>
            <td><select name="ArLevel">
                    <option value="beginner">Beginner</option>
                    <option value="intermeted">Intermeted</option>
                    <option value="advance">Advance</option>
                </select>

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Subject</td>
            <td><select name="ArSubject">
                    <option value="politic">Politic</option>
                    <option value="islamic law">Islamic Law</option>

                </select>   
            </td>
        </tr>
```

Here is my PHP Code:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
        if(!$con){
            die("Can not connect:" . mysql_error());
        }
        //Database Connection
        mysql_select_db("example",$con);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO datainsert(ArticleDate,ArticleAuthor,ArticleSource,ArLevel,ArSubject) 
        VALUES ('$_POST[ArticleDate]','$_POST[ArticleAuthor]','$_POST[ArticleSource]','$_POST[ArLebel]','$_POST[ArSubject]')";
        mysql_query($sql,$con);
        mysql_close($con);

    }
?>
```

Comment: Is this the complete form

Comment: in your HTML, it is `<select name="ArLevel">`, spelled with **v**. in your PHP  `$_POST[ArLebel]`, spelled with **b**

Answer (score 1):

There is only spelling mismatch mistack in your code:--

You are using `"ArLevel"` in the Select option ehere you are selecting a level

And you are using `$_POST["ArLebel"]` in the php code at place of `$_POST["ArLevel"]`

There is the only mistack of `b & v`

Answer (score 0):

the array keys are given as string, and strings should be enclosed in quotes, even when you are already in a string (or heredocs/nowdocs, but that's not relevant here):

It it `$variableName["keyName"]`, not `$variableName[keyName]`, unless keyName is a defined constant.

change

```
'$_POST[ArLebel]','$_POST[ArSubject]'
```

into

```
'{$_POST["ArLebel"]}','{$_POST["ArSubject"]}'
```

The {} allow for using indexed variables inside other strings.

Failing to do this correctly might yield you the notice that a string is assumed in stead of a constant.

But seen as you have a different notice message (undefined index) , it is also telling you the entire index is not found (string nor constant)... So you need to check why `$_POST["ArSubject"]` is not existing.

Have you seen Tun Zarni Kyaw's comment about probably misspelling `ArLevel` as `ArLebel` somewhere?

**warning:**

**Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection! Please sanitize your variables before putting them inside your query!**

Answer (score 0):

Use `isset()` to check the POST variables are set. Also its a good practice to escape the POST variables before inserting to database.

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
        if(!$con){
            die("Can not connect:" . mysql_error());
        }
        //Database Connection
        mysql_select_db("example",$con);

        $ArticleDate   = isset($_POST['ArticleDate'])   ? $_POST['ArticleDate'] : '';
        $ArticleAuthor = isset($_POST['ArticleAuthor']) ? $_POST['ArticleAuthor'] : '';
        $ArticleSource = isset($_POST['ArticleSource']) ? $_POST['ArticleSource'] : '';
        $ArLebel       = isset($_POST['ArLebel'])       ? $_POST['ArLebel'] : '';
        $ArSubject     = isset($_POST['ArSubject'])     ? $_POST['ArSubject'] : '';


        $sql = "INSERT INTO datainsert(ArticleDate,ArticleAuthor,ArticleSource,ArLevel,ArSubject) 
        VALUES ('$ArticleDate','$ArticleAuthor','$ArticleSource','$ArLebel','$ArSubject')";
        mysql_query($sql,$con);
        mysql_close($con);

    }
?>
```

Comment: The `isset` isn't his problem, as he already has `isset($_POST['submit']`. Only case it would fix is if someone would purposely omit variables by using the Element Inspector.